# How to get multiple urls api call in one file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, html

Hello StackOverflow Comunity, I am working on one android app which is html based gui and the problem is I want to fetch data from the api the problem is I have two parameters which uses different url to fetch data.

`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //role = localStorage.getItem("role");
    //u_name = localStorage.getItem("name");
    //$("#u_name").text(localStorage.getItem("name"));
    //$("#role").text(localStorage.getItem("role"));
    //$(".profile_image").prop("src", localStorage.getItem("profile_image"));
    //$("#main_wallet").text("₹ " + localStorage.getItem("wallet"));
    $('#app_name').text(localStorage.getItem("app_name"));
    base_url = localStorage.getItem("base_url");
    mobile = localStorage.getItem("mobile");
    password = localStorage.getItem("password");
    localStorage.setItem("prepaidSelectMountPrice", '');
    localStorage.setItem("DthSelectMountPrice", '');
    localStorage.setItem("numberEntered", "");
    localStorage.setItem("ProviderSelected", "");
    localStorage.setItem("stateSelected", "");

    $('#loader').attr('style', '');
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "api/android_app/home_data",
        type: "post",
        data: { mobile: mobile, password: password },
        success: function(res) {
            $('#loader').attr('style', 'opacity: 0.03125; display: none;');
            if (res.error == 0) {
                $('#main_wallet').text("₹ " + res.wallet_balance);
                $('#news_text').html(res.announcement);
                localStorage.setItem("upi_status", res.upi.status);
                localStorage.setItem("upi_VPA", res.upi.upi_id);
                localStorage.setItem("upi_minimumAmount", res.upi.minimum_amount);


                jQuery.each(res.sliders, function(j, value) {
                    html = '<img class="mySlides" src="' + base_url + 'slider_image/' + value.image + '" style="height:150px;width:100%;border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px !important;">'
                    $('#splide01').append(html);
                });
                carousel();
            }

        },
        complete: function() {}
    });
    
    $("#home_refresh").on("click", function() {
        $('#loader').attr('style', '');
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "api/android_app/home_data",
            type: "post",
            data: { mobile: mobile, password: password },
            success: function(res) {
                $('#loader').attr('style', 'opacity: 0.03125; display: none;');
                if (res.error == 0) {
                    $('#main_wallet').text("₹ " + res.wallet_balance);                    
                    $('#news_text').html(res.announcement);

                    $('#splide01').empty();
                    jQuery.each(res.sliders, function(j, value) {
                        html = '<img class="mySlides" src="' + base_url + 'slider_image/' + value.image + '" style="height:150px;width:100%">'
                        $('#splide01').append(html);
                    });
                    carousel();
                }

            },
            complete: function() {}
        });
    })
})

var myIndex = 0;

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) { myIndex = 1 }
    x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}


//alert();
var role_id = localStorage.getItem("role_id");
if (role_id != '6') {
    $('#manage_h6').show();
    $('#manage_1').show();
    $('#manage_2').show();
    $('#manage_3').show();
    $('#manage_4').show();
    //alert("retailer");
}
```

`

This is where the home screen fetches wallet balance now I want to fetch total recharges and and total commission which is in another url `

```
base_url = localStorage.getItem("base_url");
mobile = localStorage.getItem("mobile");
password = localStorage.getItem("password");
$('#loader').attr('style','');
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "api/android_app/day_book_reports",
            type: "post",
            data: {mobile:mobile,password:password},
            success: function (response) {
                
                var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                //console.log();           
                $('#tr_success_amount').text("₹ "+result.reports.tr_success_amount);              
                $('#tr_commission').text("₹ "+result.reports.tr_commission);
              
                
                $('#loader').attr('style','opacity: 0.03125; display: none;');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            },
        });
```

`

How I can merge this two different urls to show data on home screen. Please guide me

I have try others but it didn't work for me, please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: Serial or parallel REST calls.

**1. Serial REST calls:**

Do one REST call, then in its response, do the second call. Pseudo code:

- on document ready:

  - ajax call 1, on response:

    - ajax call 2, on response:

      - combine response 1 and 2 data, and update DOM

The user has to wait a bit more because the REST calls are done one after the other.

**2. Parallel REST calls:**

You can fire off both (or multiple) REST calls at once, then take action when both (or all) responses are received. Since it is not deterministic when a response comes back you need to store and track each REST call separately, and take action once all responses are received.

Pseudo code:

- on document ready:

  - var response1 // declare only, null
  - var response2 // declare only, null
  - ajax call 1, on response:

    - set response1 variable
    - call checkIfDone()
  - ajax call 2, on response:

    - set response1 variable
    - call checkIfDone()
  - function checkIfDone():

    - if(response1 and response2):

      - combine response1 and response2, and update DOM
    - else:

      - do nothing

The user has a faster experience because the REST calls are done in parallel.

Note on error handling: In case of an error, the response variable should be set as well, otherwise the checkIfDone() function would never take action.